# UX methods for showing "loading" UI until Firebase Cloud Function completes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an angular app for entering and calculating assessments on students, of which all the data is stored in Firebase Cloud Firestore.  When a new assessment is added I currently have the angular UI code calculating the updated averages for the student and directly updating both the student and the overall class statistics.

For numerous reasons I want to move the calculations and stat updates to cloud functions triggered on the create/update events of the Firestore documents.  I'm thinking this will be fairly easy, but then my UI will return almost immediately yet the actual statistic updates won't occur until the function is completed, potentially several seconds later.

My UI currently watches for snapshot changes, so the statistic changes will automatically be displayed once the function completed.  I'm afraid it might be confusing to the user if they enter a new assessment yet don't see the changes right away, thinking they didn't take or something went wrong.  But then several seconds later the screen suddenly shows the results of the newly updated statistics.

I'm thinking it might be a better UX to show a loading indicator until the function completes and the newly updated snapshot has been received.  I can't seem to find a suggested method or pattern for this.  How would I trigger an update and show a progress indicator until the next snapshot was received?  Should I display the indicator and then in my snapshot code look to see if the indicator is visible and remove it?

Comment: why not to ask this question in https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm looking for code suggestions specifically that relate to Angular, snapshot observables and async cloud functions triggered by a Firestore update.  While I think this could be related to almost any observable UI (angular, react, etc.) dealing with async updates I was worried that a general UX anwer would offer a lot of great usability ideas but nothing concrete on where this would be started or resolved in this code context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO I don't think you should over-complicate your UX behavior.

As you have already sketched in your question you should display a "loading indicator" when you write to the Firestore document that triggers the Cloud Function and hide this loading indicator when your snapshot changes listener indicates the statistics are updated in the back-end.

In terms of UX you could choose to show a blocking "loading indicator" or a non-blocking one, depending on the exact function of you app.

#### Non-blocking loading indicator

If, for example, the user can still work on the screen while the statistics figure is calculated in the back-end, display the loading indicator close to the statistics field (for example a small spinner with a simple text "currently updating statistics").

#### Blocking loading indicator

If, on the opposite, the user should not interact with the UI before the statistics field is updated, you can display the loading indicator in a [modal dialog box](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window) that forces the user to wait and clearly indicates that the app is working in the back-end.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, that was my initial thought but I wasn't sure that triggering on the snapshot changes was a good practice.